# Testing and mocking applications built with the AWS Rust Lambda Runtime and the AWS Rust SDK

Tags: unit-testing, rust, mocking, aws-sdk-rust, cargo-lambda

I'm currently trying to build a simple Lambda that connects to Dynamo DB with [AWS Rust Lambda Runtime](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-rust-runtime) and the [AWS Rust SDK](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-rust). My basic example works on AWS, but I'm keen to be able to perform manual tests and unit tests offline.

The main problem I can see, is in how I mock calls to and responses made via the AWS SDK.
I'm also using [Cargo Lambda](https://github.com/cargo-lambda/cargo-lambda) which includes a test server command ([cargo watch](https://www.cargo-lambda.info/commands/watch.html)), but can it be set up to mock AWS SDK calls?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS SDK includes some mocking utilities that you can use to write integration tests for your code. You can see examples for mocking the CloudWatch API here:

https://github.com/calavera/cloudwatch_logs_processor/blob/main/src/cloudwatch_logs.rs#L134

You'll have to modify that to match DynamoDB targets, and endpoints, but the premise is the same.

Comment: The link in your answer appears to be broken.